# pcolormesh: artefacts / overlapping points when using ec='face'

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I am plotting maps with pcolormesh and cartopy. When I don't use the option `edgecolor` or set it to None, results are like expected. But when I use `ec='face'`, I get really strange artefacts and/or overlapping points - depending on the selected output format.
I have tried with `snap` and `antialiased` but those don't help unfortunately.
When I zoom into the interactive plot, it looks not that bad but my output file (pdf or png) looks like a mess.

**How can I activate the edgecolor without having this weird behaviour?**

MWE below. Using
python 3.10.12,
matplotlib 3.5.1,
Cartopy 0.22.0.

```
import numpy as np
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  

proj1 = ccrs.PlateCarree()
proj2 = ccrs.LambertAzimuthalEqualArea()
fig   = plt.figure(figsize=(16,8), layout='constrained')

# generate coordinates
xx = np.linspace(-10,30,300)
yy = np.linspace( 35,75,300)
xxx,yyy = np.meshgrid(xx,yy)

rng   = np.random.default_rng(6666) 

# create artificial data
zzz = xxx + yyy 
noise = rng.normal(0,np.nanmax(zzz)*0.1,zzz.shape)
zzz += noise
 
# create some gaps in data
zdim = zzz.size
idx = rng.choice(range(zdim), size=zdim//3)

zshape  = zzz.shape
zz      = zzz.flatten()
zz[idx] = np.nan
zzz     = zz.reshape(zshape)

ax    = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1, projection=proj2)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS,   lw=0.5, ec='k')
ax.add_feature(cfeature.COASTLINE, lw=0.5, ec='k')

# looks ok    
ax.pcolormesh(xxx, yyy, zzz,
              transform=proj1)

ax = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2, projection=proj2)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS,   lw=0.5, ec='k')
ax.add_feature(cfeature.COASTLINE, lw=0.5, ec='k')

# looks not ok
ax.pcolormesh(xxx, yyy, zzz,
              #snap=True,
              #antialiased=True,
              ec='face',            # this seems to have a problem here
              transform=proj1)

plt.show()
#plt.savefig('plot_test.pdf')
```

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on the issue, I don't see anything unusual happening? You have a massive amount of overplotting due to the scale you use (icw a `linewidth=1`), but that's expected with the settings you use.

Comment: Hi, I had remembered a different behaviour, I thought the linewidth is automatically set to an optimal value. But this (decreasing `lw`) solved the problem indeed. Perhaps you would like to post it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resolution of the data is quite high in comparison to the plot size/dpi. That combined with the fact that the `edge` is actually drawn at the edge, and not confined to the inside of a quadrilateral, causes the edges to overplot adjacent data.

Increasing the figure size/dpi could help, or reducing the default linewidth of the edge to be more appropriate with respect to the size of the faces/quadrilaterals. Properties like linewidths are specified in points, which relate to the figure so it's not relative to the size/resolution of the data.

Setting the linecolor to red emphasizes the behavior a bit better perhaps. The image below is with the grid reduces to 100x100, and zoomed in a little.

```py
import numpy as np
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  

# generate coordinates
xx = np.linspace(-10,30, 100)
yy = np.linspace( 35,75, 100)
xxx,yyy = np.meshgrid(xx,yy)

rng   = np.random.default_rng(6666) 

# create artificial data
zzz = xxx + yyy 
noise = rng.normal(0,np.nanmax(zzz)*0.1,zzz.shape)
zzz += noise
 
# create some gaps in data
zdim = zzz.size
idx = rng.choice(range(zdim), size=zdim//3)

zshape  = zzz.shape
zz      = zzz.flatten()
zz[idx] = np.nan
zzz     = zz.reshape(zshape)

data_proj = ccrs.PlateCarree()
map_proj = ccrs.LambertAzimuthalEqualArea()

fig, axs = plt.subplot_mosaic(
    "ABC;DEF", figsize=(12,7), layout='constrained', 
    subplot_kw={"projection": map_proj}, facecolor="w",
)

axs["A"].set_title("No edge")
axs["A"].pcolormesh(xxx, yyy, zzz, transform=data_proj)

axs["B"].set_title("edge=face, default lw")
axs["B"].pcolormesh(xxx, yyy, zzz, transform=data_proj, ec='face')

axs["C"].set_title("edge=face, small lw")
axs["C"].pcolormesh(xxx, yyy, zzz, transform=data_proj, ec='face', lw=0.1)

axs["D"].set_title("No edge")
axs["D"].pcolormesh(xxx, yyy, zzz, transform=data_proj)

axs["E"].set_title("edge=r, default lw")
axs["E"].pcolormesh(xxx, yyy, zzz, transform=data_proj, ec='r')

axs["F"].set_title("edge=r, small lw")
axs["F"].pcolormesh(xxx, yyy, zzz, transform=data_proj, ec='r', lw=0.1)

for ax in axs.values():
    ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS,   lw=0.5, ec='k', alpha=.5)
    ax.add_feature(cfeature.COASTLINE, lw=0.5, ec='k', alpha=.5)
    ax.set_extent((0, 30, 60, 76), crs=data_proj)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the elaborated answer! (And also for demonstrating `subplot_mosaic` - never used that before.)